# Why are my div elements shifting when the container div has overflow: auto set

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Here is an example of the offending code... Note, this code works as expected in FireFox. The problem is in Internet Explorer.

```js
function init() {
    $(".listOUT").bind("mouseenter", function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('listOUT', false);
        $(this).toggleClass('listIN', true);
      })
      .bind("mouseleave", function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('listIN', false);
        $(this).toggleClass('listOUT', true);
      });
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.controlContainer {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
}
.listOUT {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 85%;
  border: solid 1px #7F9DB9;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /*
     background:url('images/ddImage_out.gif') no-repeat right center;
     */
}
.listIN {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 85%;
  border: inset 1px #7F9DB9;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /*
        background:url('images/ddImage_in.gif') no-repeat right center;
        */
}
.listTEXT {
  text-transform: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 8pt;
  color: Black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style> </head> <body onload="init();"> <form id="form1" runat="server"> <div style="width:600px; height:200px;"> <div id="container" style="overflow:auto;position:relative;width:100%; height:100%;"> <div id="control1Container" style="left:67%;top:105px;width:15%;" class=
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('jquery', '1.3.1');
</script>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="width:600px; height:200px;">
    <div id="container" style="overflow:auto;position:relative;width:100%; height:100%;">
      <div id="control1Container" style="left:67%;top:105px;width:15%;" class="controlContainer">
        <div id="control1" class="listOUT">
          <input type="text" class="listTEXT" id="ddTextBox1" readonly="readonly" value="Digital" name="ddTextBox1" />
          <input type="hidden" value="1" id="selSelected1" name="selSelected1" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="control3Container" style="left:50%;top:15px;width:36%;" class="controlContainer">
        <div id="control3" class="listOUT">I am a control</div>
      </div>
      <div id="control4Container" style="left:40%;top:145px;width:36%;" class="controlContainer">
        <div id="control4" class="listOUT">I am a control</div>
      </div>
      <div id="control2Container" style="left:47%;top:225px;width:36%;" class="controlContainer">
        <div id="control2" class="listOUT">I am a control</div>
      </div>
      <!-- more controls here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using? The behavior is the same in firefox as in IE7&IE6 even.

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 8

Comment: Soo.. What exactly is your problem, how SHOULD it look?

Comment: When I move over one of the controls, it shifts to the right.  This should not happen.  This only happens when there is a vertical scrollbar. ie. There is at least one control that is out of view in the container div.  The control border should change colour on mouseenter and mouseleave, but the control should remain in a fixed position.

Comment: Could be just me but when I use your code, the controls stay in the same place when moused over. (In either FF, ie6&7&8)

When I mouse over the "digital" box, my firebug gives me an error:

"Permission denied to access property 'parentNode' from a non-chrome context

Line 19"

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you mean. When I opened your web page in Internet Explorer 8 and pointed at the controls, they moved to the left.

I have very little experience of javascript and have never used jquery, but if all you want to do is change border colour on mouseenter and mouseleave I may be able to help you out.

Go to http://www.mkforlag.com/eng_contact/ and click in the light blue fields to see the border change to brown and the background to yellow. Is it an effect similar to this you want to achieve?